# Why it throws `GeoDjango Postgis requirements not satisfied getting error while running migrations?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, postgis, geodjango

I am using Postgresql database with django and have already installed in PostGis on it using

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

The `gdal`, `proj.4` and `geos` are already installed in `contrib.gis django package`. As the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/gis/install/postgis/) says they should be installed prior installing PostGis. Does that mean they should be installed on Postgresql database or something else.

1)Do I need to install them on postgresql database aswell?

So far I have included in `settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
      .
      .
      'django.contrib.gis',
]

DATABASES = {
        'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': '......',
        'USER' : '.........',
        'PASSWORD': '........',
        'HOSTNAME': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    },
}
```

But when I included this in `models.py`.

```
 from django.contrib.gis.db import models as geomodels
```

2) I tried to run the migrations I am getting this error:

```
 django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not find the GDAL library (tried "gdal202", "gdal201", "gdal20", "gdal111", "gdal110", "gdal19"). Is GDAL in
```

stalled? If it is, try setting GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH in your settings.

I am not sure what should I fix to run the migrations and If this error is related to database or django

3)Do I need to install the `Gdal`, `Geos` and `proj` on both django and postgresql?

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow below steps for setup post GIS in your project as per documentation:

1. Install [GEOS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/#geosbuild), [PROJ.4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/#proj4) and [GDAL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/#gdalbuild) on your machine where postgres is installed prior to installing **PostGIS** extension to your project. Installation documentation has been included in link. You can check PostGIS install requirements from [here](https://postgis.net/docs/postgis_installation.html#install_requirements).

   - [For installing GEOS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/#geosbuild)
   - [For installing PROJ.4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/#proj4)
   - [For installing GDAL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/#gdalbuild)
2. Create spatial database. After installing above requirements **create PostGIS extension**. You can do it by executing following code into your postgres shell

   ```
   > CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
   ```

   or you can add following migration to your project

   ```
   from django.contrib.postgres.operations import CreateExtension
   from django.db import migrations

   class Migration(migrations.Migration):

       operations = [
           CreateExtension('postgis'),
           ...
       ]
   ```

   [Visit here for more information](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/gis/install/postgis/#creating-a-spatial-database)
3. After that you can add below to your `settings.py`

   ```
   DATABASES = {
       'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
            'NAME': 'geodjango',
            'USER': 'geo',
       },
   }

   INSTALLED_APPS = [
       ..
       ..
       'django.contrib.admin',
       'django.contrib.gis',
       ..
       ..

   ]
   ```

After following these steps you can use django PostGIS. for more information on installation of PostGIS visit https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#setting-up

Comment: But when I am using postgresql for database for my all apps and after using postgis as my default database, Isn't going to cause any kind of error.

Comment: This is  normal **postgis** just wraps all functionalities of **postgres**

Comment: Ok, But If I try to run the server after using postgis as the database engine it is still giving me error of django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not find the GDAL library (tried "gdal202", "gdal201", "gdal20", "gdal111", "gdal110", "gdal19"). Is GDAL in
stalled? If it is, try setting GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH in your settings.

Comment: Have you installed `GDAL` in your machine? Please check out [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/#gdaltrouble) for more information.

Comment: I have downloaded the OSGeo4W package that has the gdal in it and I have also setup the system variable according to the documentation but it is still giving the error. According to the documetation if the file is at non standard location then we can specify the path to it which is for libgdal.so file but I don't have that file anywhere in the package.